# I'm having a problem about my button at my html code

Tags: html, css

On the sidebar there was supposed to be a button that only appears when I remove the padding does anyone knows why? I realized the button goes down to the page and I can't see it.

**that what it looks like with padding**

[image: that what it looks like with padding]

**and this one is without padding**

[image: and this one is without padding]

```
aside.sidebar{
    position:fixed;
    height:100%;
    background:#15c3d6;
    padding:5px 24px;
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:column;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items:center;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the padding is pushing the button ofscreen. Remove `10px` from the header's height and you should be fine:

```
aside.sidebar {
  position: fixed;
  height: calc(100% - 10px);
  background: #15c3d6;
  padding: 5px 24px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}
```